# Updating a Script

Tags: sql, t-sql

A while back I created a script that SUMS the number of Employees we have and the number of terms we have. It was rather simple when they used "Active" and "Withdrawn" as the status. Now they have updated the status to include "Continuous LOA" and "Retiree" as an additional status.

What I need to know is how do I update the below script to include these to new parameters. Continuous LOA would fall with the Active and Retiree would fall with the Withdrawn.

```
MERGE   dbo.HRIS_HC_SumTotals AS tgt
USING   (
    SELECT  DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS [Year],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HistoricalHC,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName = 'Withdrawn' AND TermYear = DATENAME(YEAR,     GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumbOfTermEE
    FROM    dbo.HRIS_HC_MstrTbl
    WHERE   ChangeStatus = 'Current'
        AND EmpStatusName IN ('Active', 'Withdrawn')
) AS src ON src.[Year] = tgt.[Year]
WHEN    MATCHED
    THEN    UPDATE
        SET tgt.HistoricalHC = src.HistoricalHC,
            tgt.NumbTermedEmp = src.NumbOfTermEE
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN    INSERT  (
                [Year],
                HistoricalHC,
                NumbTermedEmp
            )
        VALUES  (
                src.[Year],
                src.HistoricalHC,
                src.NumbOfTermEE
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change 2 lines of code to be 'in' statements:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName in ('Active','Continuous LOA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HistoricalHC,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmpStatusName in ('Withdrawn','Retiree') AND TermYear = DATENAME(YEAR,     GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumbOfTermEE
```

and change the Where statement

```
AND EmpStatusName IN ('Active', 'Withdrawn', 'Continuous LOA','Retiree')
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave an error.

Comment: Without the error message it's hard to be of further help.

Comment: it just said incorrect syntax, (sorry). I'm thinking there is an issue with the parenthesis.

Comment: Not sure, sorry.  The code I updated seems solid on the surface.  If your code works without my updates it should work when you add them also unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I missed the "IN" statement. This worked correctly. Thank you for your assistance.